# Confused about negation within a proof

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I wanted to come up with a proof using contrapositive, so **I needed the negation of the following: "one of x and y is congruent to 1 modulo 6 while the other is congruent to 5 modulo 6."**

I interpreted this statement as being the same as "one of x and y is congruent to 1 modulo 6 and the other is congruent to 5 modulo 6", so **the negation I got was "one of x and y is not congruent to 1 modulo 6 or the other is not congruent to 5 modulo 6".**

Turns out the negation is "one of x and y is not congruent to 1 or 5 modulo 6."

I'm not seeing it. Please help me understand.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Not ($p$ and $q$) is equivalent to not $p$ **or** not $q$

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, we may assume your statement is, in effect,

$$x \equiv 1 \pmod 6 \land y \equiv 5 \pmod 6$$

(This is equivalent since, in the end, the assignments of $x,y$ are arbitrary since they're not further defined outside of these properties.) Then why is the negation of this

$$x \not \equiv 1 \pmod 6 \lor y \not \equiv 5 \pmod 6$$

instead of your suggestion?

---

The issue lies, fundamentally, with the logical "and" ($\land$) operator. If $P \land Q$ is true, that means $P,Q$ individually are both true. What would be the negation of that, then? It would be whenever $P \land Q$ is false, i.e. one of the following holds:

- $P$ false, $Q$ true
- $P$ true, $Q$ false
- $P,Q$ both false

This can be summarized more succinctly as "at least one of $P,Q$ are false," or perhaps even more clearly as "$P$ is false or $Q$ is false."

Symbolically, this would be notated $\neg (P \land Q) = \neg P \lor \neg Q$ -- the negation of an "and" statement, in other words, is one of the comprising statements of it is false.

Comment: But this allows $y\equiv 5\pmod 6$ and $x\equiv 1\pmod 6$.  Which *could* be how the author intended but I doubt it.  I think the statement is $(x\equiv 1\land y \equiv 5)\lor (x\equiv 5\land y\equiv 1)$ and the negation is $\lnot(x\equiv 1\land x\equiv 5)\land\lnot(x\equiv 5\land y\equiv 1)=(x\not\equiv 1\lor y\not \equiv 5)\land(x\not\equiv 5\lor y\not \equiv 1)$

Answer (score 0):

they are both wrong.

I see the statement as, the set of congruences of the set $x,y$ is the set $1,5$.

The negation of that is, the set of congruences of the set $x,y$ is *not* the set $1,5$.

So they could both be congruent to $1$, the could both be congruent to $5$, one could be congruent to $1$ and the other to anything else  but $5$, one could be congruent to $5$ and the other to anything else but $1$, or they could both be congruent to something other than $1$ or $5$.